# What webservices are available to obtain miles between two addresses?

Tags: web-services, distance, street-address

I need to find a way to get miles (not a straight line) between two locations by passing the post addresses.

If you consider the simplicity of implementation, efficiency and stability, which webservice(s) you can suggest?

I would appreciate if you know any possible comparison list of relevant web-services.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found basically what I need here:
http://briancray.com/2009/06/23/calculate-driving-distance-google-maps-api/

Other than that here is a nice comparision chart os mapping services:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_map_services

Cheers!
burak ozdogan